# L1 norm equality constraints in portfolio optimization, pros and cons

Tags: portfolio-optimization

Can I use L1 norm equality constraints $\sum_{i}{|w_i|}=c,~c>0$ (or $\|\mathbf{w}\|_1=c$) in portfolio optimization, instead of the $\sum_{i}{w_i}=c$ (or $\mathbf{1}^T\mathbf{w}=c$) constraint?
Any implications, pros, and cons?

Thanks for the comments below. I try to summarize what we have for now:

> - L1 norm equality constraint is conservative and backups all short positions.
> - It generalizes both equal-weight long and equal-weight short.
> - However, it prevents exact-form solutions.

Comment: "L1 norm constraints" in portfolio optimization (De Miguel, 2009) are of the form $\sum_i |w_i| < C$ and they do not replace the constraint $\sum_i w_i = 1$.  See for example p12 here http://facultyresearch.london.edu/docs/DeMiguelGarlappiNogalesUppal20070715.pdf You seem to be using the term in a different sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: In Markowitz' original work he did suggest that one could choose *either* $\sum w_i = 1$ or $\sum |w_i| = 1$ in the portfolio problem, depending how one thinks short sales should be treated. But nowadays most people agree that $\sum w_i = 1$ is the right way to go and you don't see the other formulation very often in the literature. So I am puzzled what you are asking.

Comment: @nbbo2 thanks for letting me know. I was thinking if I can use $\|\mathbf{w}\|_1=1$ then I can include both equal long-weight portfolios and equal short-weight portfolios (for mkt downturn). could you share which Markowitz's paper is talking about this topic?

Comment: The $l1$ norm constraint is a no-leverage constraint. It's nonlinear, which prevents explicit solutions. It is a sensible constraint if for every dollar you have in the portfolio, you want to keep a dollar to back it up (esp for shorts).